# How to connect to H2 database using jmeter?

Tags: java, database, jdbc, jmeter, h2

I am using Jmeter with JDBC to connect to h2 database. I have created JDBC connection configuration in the Jmeter Test Plan and given variable name as 'mydb' and my JDBC configuration is as follows:

```
    database connection URL: jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/d:/h2/sample
               Driver class: org.h2.Driver
                   Username: sa
```

I have created a JDBC request under the Thread Group and am using the same variable name 'mydb' for the jdbc request. The jmeter throws me an exception.. `Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Connection is broken: "unexpected status 16777216" [90067-176])`
however, i am able to access the database on my browser.

I am using the below link as a reference for what i am doing:

https://www.coursehero.com/file/p6a7t19/1-Set-up-an-H2-database-Download-an-H2-database-distribution-from/

Any hints on what i am missing??